# JS/React - cannot read property "X" of undefined, unable to access method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

bit of a React noob here and I've searched a fair bit for solutions to this issue, however I'm still confused. In short, I have a dropdown menu with a list of numbers, rendered from an array via map. The intent is to be able to change the value of "coloursValue" via setState by clicking on one of the buttons from the dropdown menu. Everything renders correctly, however when I attempt to click one of the buttons I am met w/ the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeValue' of undefined". I understand this is likely an issue relating to scope and "this" not being properly defined, yet changeValue is bound in the constructor. What am I doing wrong, and how can I rectify this?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
let colours = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let coloursMapped = mapItems(colours, "coloursValue");


function mapItems(input, context) {
  let listItems = input.map(item =>
  <DropdownItem key={item}>
    <button onClick={() => this.changeValue.bind(this)}>
      {item}
    </button>
  </DropdownItem>
  );
  return <DropdownMenu right>
    {listItems}
  </DropdownMenu>
}

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
  this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    coloursValue: "# of Colours",
    dropdownOpen: [false, false, false]
  };
}

changeValue(value, context) {
  // modify "coloursValue" via setState according to the number 
  // selected via the "onClick" handler in "mapItems"
}

toggle(index) {
  let dropdownState = this.state.dropdownOpen.slice();
  dropdownState[index] = !this.state.dropdownOpen[index];
  this.setState({
    dropdownOpen: dropdownState
  });
}
```

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong"* When you call a function the "normal" way, i.e. `foo()`, then `this` either refers to the global object or `undefined` in strict mode. So, when you call `mapItems(colours, "coloursValue");`, `this` is `undefined`, and therefore `this` is `undefined` in `() => this.changeValue.bind(this)` (which btw is not even calling `this.changeValue`). Basically you are trying to reference the component instance before it even exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `mapItems` exists outside of the class, so it doesn't have access to the class scope to bind `changeValue`. Move `mapItems` into the `App` component and it should work. You should also move `colours` and `coloursMapped` into the `App` component as state.

Comment: Even once you fix that, it's still not going to work because of this `<button onClick={() => this.changeValue.bind(this)}>`

That line returns a new function instead of calling this.changeValue

Comment: Yep you're absolutely right, didn't skim over all the code. Change the onClick to `<button onClick={this.changeValue}>`

Comment: much appreciated, thank you for the explanation and the help